# How to get the specific data in nested node in Firebase

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the name of the specific user in my firebase but i can not access since it is nested i used.

```
orderbychild("userid").equalto(currentuserid)
```

and try to used toast if it's existed, yes it is existing but when i get the value of name using

```
String name=datasnapshot.child("name").getvalue.tostring()
```

My app suddenly crashed

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: check logcat, can be android side problem. Also share firebase structure, if possible.